# Regions on Snowflake, what is the best practice for setting up our VPN if we have two regions

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am setting up the VPN to connect to Snowflake in two different regions, us-west and ap-southeast-2.

I am setting up network policies to use a set of ip ranges used in our VPN via
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/network-policies.html#network-policy-properties

Like:

```
Allowed IP Addresses: 192.168.1.0/24
- Blocked IP Addresses: 192.168.1.99
```

Can I also do this on a warehouse by warehouse basis, regardless of the region, for specific roles?

Comment: This sounds like a feature request as network policies can only be configured by account today and not across accounts. I know there an existing feature request called "Network Policy per Role" on the Snowflake Ideas page, but you can also add your own if that doesn't quite describe what you are looking for.  The Ideas page link is below.    https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake network policies work only at the account level, so you cannot set them for a warehouse.

In the larger context, a network policy is a Snowflake parameter. Parameters form a hierarchy like this: Account > User > Session. Snowflake also has Object (table, view) parameters.

On this page of the docs, you can see that NETWORK_POLICY is an account parameter:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html

If you must have multiple network policies, you would need to have multiple accounts. Your account team can set this up for you, but there are drawbacks to using multiple accounts. For example you would need to use data sharing to join tables between the accounts.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#managing-user-level-network-policies this seems to imply that you can create user-level network policies.

Comment: Yes, you can now do that. I'm not sure when it got added, but you can now set network policies for users.